# Why does Lidar define a decoherence-free subspace as "a subspace that undergoes purely unitary evolution"

Tags: entanglement, decoherence

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.5791.pdf) from 2014, Lidar defines: "an open system which undergoes purely unitary evolution (possibly only in a subspace of its Hilbert space) is said to be decoherence-free." Why is this the chosen definition? Naively, it seems to be overly strict.

In particular, I would guess that we would want to call a subspace "decoherence-free" when there exists a pointer basis for that subspace according to the predictability sieve criterion (or a better criterion). I.e., not that the effective dynamics have to be unitary within the subspace, but that the there exists a basis for this subspace such that each basis vector does not entangle (very much) with the environment (modeled a certain way) under evolution of the total Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 2):

We can think of decoherence as a loss of the system information to the environment. So then, what would be the opposite of that, where there is no loss of the system information to the environment? *Decoherence-free*! And it is precisely what unitary evolution does.

If a subspace of total Hilbert space experiences unitary evolution, then it preserves the total information within the subspace, there is no leakage of the information to the environment, and there is no loss of information (Although the information would be scrambled within the subspace). Hence, we can say that the subspace is *decoherence-free*.

Read the section $\text{II(C)}$ from the same paper, and you should get some insight into the motivation behind this definition of decoherence-free.